# Is there an easy/elementary way to show that if $f_k\to f \in L^p(\Omega)$ we can conclude that $\int |f_k|^p\to \int |f|^p$

Tags: reference-request, lp-spaces

Hey just stumbled upon this problem.

Often one finds the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem presented for $L^1$ spaces with the statement that the integrals do converge, i.e. $\int f_k \to \int f$.

However, in the versions for $L^p$ spaces with $p\in(1,\infty)$ this statement is missing (at least in my references) i.e. one does not find $\int |f_k|^p\to \int |f|^p$. 
I found one reference that gives a positive answer: From $f_k\to f \in L^p$ one can conclude that $|f_k|^p \to |f|^p \in L^1$. However the proof I found relies on the Vitali convergence theorem. Is there a more elementary proof to conclude the convergence of the integrals?

Comment: Do you know Minkowski's inequality?

Comment: sure, but I wasn't yet able to figure out how this helps :)

Comment: Try applying it to the sum $(f-f_k) +f_k$.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my question correctly or if I'm just not seeing how this helps to get from $||f_k|^p -|f|^p|$ to something better. Applying Minkowski would yield an additional term $2^{p-1} |f|^p$ i.e. the we would end up with the good term $2^{p-1}|f-f_k|^p$ but we still have in  brackets $(2^{p-1}-1) |f|$. The latter term does not vanish.

Comment: Lebesgue theorem is elementary for you?

Comment: I haven't thought of it yet. But I think it would be elementary enough for me though my intention was to find something like an estimate of the type $||f_k|^p -|f|^p|\leq |f_k-f|^p$ (which is of course not clear and would probably only work on bounded domains). However, coming back to Lebesgue's theorem. From where do you get the dominating function? For this we need to know that $|f_k|^p \to |f|^p \in L^1$. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: If $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\Omega)$, then there exist a subsequence of $f_n$ (not relabeled) and $g\in L^p(\Omega)$ such that $f_n\to f$ a.e in $\Omega$ and $|f_n|\leq g$. Now, you can apply Lebesgue theorem to conclude.

Comment: From where do you get the $g$? Haven't seen this part of the conclusion before (pointwise convergence for a subsequence is clear)

Comment: Take a look in page 94, Theorem 4.9. http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni.wroc.pl%2F~karch%2Fanaliza_nieliniowa%2Fref%2FBREZIS__Functional_Analysis__Sobolev_Spaces_and_Partial_Differential_Equations__Universitext_.pdf&ei=YyQ-Up7CB9PG4AOP34Bg&usg=AFQjCNGP9nqQmNf4F1EOrBbb_glm25twWQ&bvm=bv.52434380,d.dmg

Comment: Maybe @NateEldredge could give us another hint. His method seems more elementary

Comment: @Tomas. Thanks for the link. Unfortunately my "main book" is not using the dominating function provided by the Fischer-Riesz theorem but your answer suffices. Could you post an answer? Nevertheless I'm also interested in what Nat Eldredge wanted to suggest.

Comment: Let's wait more, if we don't get any answer, I post mine.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but the following more general statement is true (by using the triangle inequality (which is Minkowski's inequality in your case))
If $(X,||.||)$ is a normed space, and if a sequence $(x_k)\subset X$ converges to $x\in X$, then $||x_k||$ converges to $||x||$ as well...

Comment: sranthrop's comment is what I had in mind, and it's now in Tomás's answer.

Comment: @Tomás I think what the OP meant by [From $f_k\to f \in L^p$] in [From $f_k\to f \in L^p$ one can conclude that $|f_k|^p \to |f|^p \in L^1$] was the pointwise convergence. And the statement would be _poinwise convergence + limit in $L^p$ implies convergence in norm._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Normed space and assume that $x_n\to x$. By one hand, note that $$\|x_n\|=\|x_n-x+x\|\leq\|x_n-x\|+\|x\|$$

On the other hand $$\|x\|=\|x-x_n+x_n\|\leq \|x_n-x\|+\|x_n\|$$

which implies that $$\tag{1}|\|x_n\|-\|x\||\leq\|x_n-x\|$$

From $(1)$ we conclude that $\|x_n\|\to\|x\|$.

To answer Op's question, we apply the previous result by taking $X=L^p(\Omega)$ and noting that the function $x\mapsto x^p$ is continuous for $p\geq 1$.

Remark: This answer was considerably improved by @sranthrop.

Comment: There is no need for X to be complete. Your (and my) statement follows immediately from the reverse triangle inequality, that is $\left|\ ||x||-||y||\ \right|\leq ||x-y||$.

Comment: Yes, you are right @sranthrop I am doing so much thing for nothing

Comment: We should add the following: The original problem asked to proof $||x_k||^p\to||x||^p$, but this should be clear now, since $y\mapsto y^p$ is a continuous map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ for each $p\geq1$.

Comment: Ok @sranthrop, I have added your observation, thank you for your comments.

Comment: @tomas, sranthrop and Nate Eldredge. I didn't think of the continuity. Shame on me. Thanks for your efforts. Now everything is clear.